# Additional parameters when using intel.xdk.file.uploadToServer?

Tags: javascript, php, parameters, intel, intel-xdk

I'm using Intel XDK to create a smartphone application. Currently I'm uploading a captured photograph by using intel.xdk.file.uploadToServer as shown in their documentation. This is working fully, however I would like to send additional parameters to the back-end (PHP) other than just those required by the 'uploadToServer' function.

What should I do / use?

Comment: what kind of additional parameters? data parameter in POST ?

Comment: Yeah, like just 'hello' in example.

Comment: which example, u have a link?

Answer (score 1):

The uploadToServer file API does not allow you to specify additional parameters than what is documented.

I would use Parse JavaScript APIs that allow you to easily save an object and link to an uploaded file, here is an example:

```
 Parse.initialize("YOUR KEY GOES HERE"); //API key

 //whatever you want to call your storage object
 var PhotoDetails = Parse.Object.extend("PhotoDetails"); 

 //create new instance of your Parse Object
 var photoDetails = new PhotoDetails(); 

 //you can add each param separately and save      
 photoDetails.set("paramname", "value");
 photoDetails.save();

 //or use object literal notation
 photoDetails.save({category: "landscape", 
                   description: "a very cool photo", 
                   location: "33.38453, -28.234234"
                   }).then(function(object) {
                         alert("Photo Recorded!);
                  });
```

You can also store the actual photo or filetype in the cloud up to 10MB per file. Parse determines the file type by the file extension or you can specify the type in the optional third param below:

```
//see https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#files 
//for base 64 or HTML file input examples
 var parseFile = new Parse.File("myphoto.jpg", fileData, "image/jpg");

 parseFile.save().then(function() {
   alert("The file has been saved to Parse.");
 }, function(error) {
   console.log("The file either could not be read, or could not be saved to Parse.");
 });
```

You can associate a Parse File with a Parse Object by using:

```
  photoDetails.set("photoFile", file);
  photoDetails.save();
```

Then in the cloud you can login to Parse and you will see your object type in the Data Browser view with your photo image and all the other params you specified.

For more info see: https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#javascript_guide